# Detox tests are assigned to Undefined, and all e2e are skipped

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, detox

1. I installed jest and detox on a fresh `react-native init` project.
2. Install jest and jest-circus as per detox docs
3. Setup iOS build and test configuration
4. Get the following error consistently on new builds

my .detoxrc.json file:

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/rndetox.xcworkspace -scheme rndetox -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rndetox.app",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "binaryPath": "SPECIFY_PATH_TO_YOUR_APP_BINARY",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_2_API_29"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

detox config.json

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "./environment",
    "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
    "testTimeout": 120000,
    "testRegex": "\\.e2e\\.js$",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
}
```

and `e2e/environment.js`

```
const {
  DetoxCircusEnvironment,
  SpecReporter,
  WorkerAssignReporter,
} = require('detox/runners/jest-circus');

class CustomDetoxEnvironment extends DetoxCircusEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);

    // Can be safely removed, if you are content with the default value (=300000ms)
    this.initTimeout = 300000;

    // This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, Jest only reports at file-level.
    // This is strictly optional.
    this.registerListeners({
      SpecReporter,
      WorkerAssignReporter,
    });
  }
}

module.exports = CustomDetoxEnvironment;
```

I have tried including an `init.js` with a `detox.init` but same error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey! If you got a solution since you posted that, I'd love to hear it. I'm struggling exactly like you… Thanks guys

Comment: I actually did fi it @GuillaumeS., turns out detox is/was not support on `0.63` yet which just released a few days ago...I had to do a fresh react native install at 0.62 and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I tried this, detox was not supported yet on the fresh 0.63 release of React Native. If you build a new project at 0.62 it should be fine. I am not sure if this has been fixed yet though!

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for your answer. That's weird though, I'm still at 0.61.5 and it's not working. I'll try to update then. Thanks a lot!