# Detox e2e Test assigned to undefined and all tests skipped

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, detox

In our react-native project we use detox for e2e test. These were working fine until suddenly we experienced the test suites being assigned to undefined. Weirdly this problem persisted upon reverting any changes to a state where detox was working previously. The problem exists in both, the iOS and Android configurations.

[Console error of Detox, assigned to undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O07wV.png)

(This problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919444/detox-tests-are-assigned-to-undefined-and-all-e2e-are-skipped) question, however, as of now detox should work with our react native version.)

My  `detoxrc.json`:

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Test-iphonesimulator/Cliniserve One.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/shiftapp.xcworkspace -scheme shiftapp.test -configuration Test -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/development/debug/shiftapp_development_debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDevelopmentDebug assembleDevelopmentDebugAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_API_29_AOSP"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `e2e/config.json`

```
{
    "setupFilesAfterEnv" : ["./init.js"],
    "testEnvironment": "./environment",
    "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
    "testTimeout": 120000,
    "testRegex": "\\.e2e\\.js$",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
}
```

And `e2e/environment.js`

```
const {
  DetoxCircusEnvironment,
  SpecReporter,
  WorkerAssignReporter,
} = require('detox/runners/jest-circus');

class CustomDetoxEnvironment extends DetoxCircusEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);

    // Can be safely removed, if you are content with the default value (=300000ms)
    this.initTimeout = 300000;

    // This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, Jest only reports at file-level.
    // This is strictly optional.
    this.registerListeners({
      SpecReporter,
      WorkerAssignReporter,
    });
  }
}

module.exports = CustomDetoxEnvironment;
```

Any help or idea on how to get it to work again would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the output of `$ adb devices` and `$ xcrun simctl list`? do you see the devices you have in your config listed?